# What do I need to develop SharePoint applications?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm a .NET developer and I'm used to write standard WinForms and ASP.NET applications.

In a few months I'll engage in a project that requires Sharepoint development. Problem is... I'm on ground zero regarding Sharepoint, and I have no idea how Sharepoint works.

What software / tools do I need to have to be able to study and develop sharepoint applications? I've noticed there's a "SharePoint Server 2007", do I need that? What about Office, do I need a special version of Office to develop for Sharepoint?

And a second question is: how do these things connect and integrate? Visual Studio, IIS, SharePoint Server, Office... ?

Any overview on this would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much a duplicate of:

- [SharePoint development environment setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581050/sharepoint-development-environment-setup/581934);
- [Creating a development environment for SharePoint.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676/creating-a-development-environment-for-sharepoint);
- [How to begin as a .net and SharePoint developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182449/how-to-begin-as-a-net-and-sharepoint-developer); and
- [What setup do you use for SharePoint (WSS/MOSS) development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636813/what-setup-do-you-use-for-sharepoint-wss-moss-development).

Answer (score 1):

Read [Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (Pattison,Larson)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201).  If you are already familiar with C# and ASP.NET, this book is **THE** book to read to ensure you are aware of how to develop WSS/MOSS applications.  This book is a **MUST HAVE** if you want to properly develop SharePoint solutions/applications.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pete's recommendation of the Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (Pattison,Larson) book.  I would also recommend the [The Great SharePoint Adventure](http://www.tedpattison.net/Courses/GSA401.aspx) class taught by Ted Pattison (if/when that is an option for you).  I took the class and it helped fill in a lot of the gaps in my knowledge.  It follows his book closely.

I would also recommend that you look at [SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/FX100487631033.aspx) too (now a free download).  While not a programming tool it fills the gap between the web interface and Visual Studio.  For some tasks it is the quickest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the Sharepoint Designer it is not development it is more customization of one site...

If you have a more mature deploy model then you need to write solutions see 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957.aspx

What is your requirements__ What should you write. My experience sitting in Sharepoint land the last 2 years is that is not a silver bullet. You can easily get much more problems with performance, deployment etc. because you tried to use Sharepoint for everything....