# Running Sharepoint site connection in to VS

Tags: sharepoint

I have running Sharepoint website and would like to make some enhancement in that, I have installed VS 2010 on my computer but dont know how to connect running sharepoint site in to VS 2010? Any one can suggest for the same.

Comment: Best practices: Read related questions here and on sharepoint.stackexchange.net, watch Microsoft Virtual Academy courses, buy a paid computer-based or instructor-led training, read some books, articles and blogs.

Answer (score 1):

its duplicate of:

- [SharePoint development environment setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581050/sharepoint-development-environment-setup/581934);
- [Creating a development environment for SharePoint.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676/creating-a-development-environment-for-sharepoint);
- [How to begin as a .net and SharePoint developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182449/how-to-begin-as-a-net-and-sharepoint-developer); and
- [What setup do you use for SharePoint (WSS/MOSS) development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636813/what-setup-do-you-use-for-sharepoint-wss-moss-development).